# Can't install local NuGet package

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

## Details

- Using Visual Studio 2017
- Built NuGet package with NuGet Package Explorer
- Placed .nupkg file in local folder on disk
- Added folder to Package Sources in Visual Studio
- I attempt to install the package using the Visual Studio GUI (Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...).

## Problem

My package shows up in the list in the GUI, but when I click install, an error message says it can't find the package in the folder I put the .nupkg file in:

```
Package 'TDDeviceIntegration 1.0.0' is not found in the following primary source(s): 'C:\Users\j.smith\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\LocalNugetRepository\'. Please verify all your online package sources are available (OR) package id, version are specified correctly.
```

## What I've tried

- Putting the NuGet Package I've built in several different local folder locations and adding those to the Package Sources, all with the same result (it can't find the package I JUST put there).
- I've restarted Visual Studio several times.
- I've restarted my computer.
- I've cleared my NuGet cache(s) from Visual Studio

## Question

How do I diagnose this?  How do I fix this?  I just want to make sure that the NuGet package works locally before I give it to the rest of the team.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the filename of your `nupkg`? what's the entry in `packages.config`?

Comment: @orhtej2 The name of my .nupkg file is `TDDeviceIntegration 1.0.0.nupkg` and I can't get an entry for it in packages.config because it won't install

Comment: does it work if you rename it to `TDDeviceIntegration.1.0.0.nupkg`? (dot instead of space between package name and version).

Comment: @orhtej2, I'll try that next

Comment: DING DING DING @orhtej2!  Changing the space in the name of the .nupkg file is what allowed the installation to seem to be successful!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you want to write an answer I can accept?

Comment: @orhtej2, Could you please convert your comment to the answer, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread and find the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT The problem is I cannot find any reference on why (if?) dot is really the only allowed package name-version separator.

Comment: I'm asking everyone... is the lacking reference a problem? I'm not sure about current rules, but I'd like to find @orhtej2's answer as marked anyway, rather than scavenging the comments. It's been useful and it may be so to others...

Comment: @orhtej2,@Francesco B. At this moment, The closest document I can find is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#choosing-a-unique-package-identifier-and-setting-the-version-number, It said "Namespace-like names: Follow a pattern similar to namespaces in .NET, using dot notation instead of hyphens.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I diagnose this? How do I fix this? I just want to make sure that the NuGet package works locally before I give it to the rest of the team.

Just as @orhtej2 comment, you should:

> you rename it to TDDeviceIntegration.1.0.0.nupkg? (dot instead of
>   space between package name and version).

Additional, some info about why dot is really the only allowed package name-version separator.

That because **namespace of nuget package follows a pattern similar to namespaces in .NET, using dot notation instead of hyphens.**

You can get the source from following document:

[Choosing a unique package identifier and setting the version number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#choosing-a-unique-package-identifier-and-setting-the-version-number)

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's a bummer that the NuGet Package Explorer project is the one creating file names with spaces in it... :(

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I had a similar issue but not with a space but rather a dash, so mypackage-1.0.0.0.nupkg. This worked fine when pulling from a remote NuGet repository but when trying to download it and install it locally it only worked if I changed the dash to a dot, so mypackage.1.0.0.0.nupkg

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link from the NuGet GitHub Repository](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2307), you can possibly encounter this error when the version of your package is not "normalized", i.e. it's not made up of 4 digits.
Yours has 3 digits, so...

(and the last digit might have to be 0).

Comment: Interesting.  I tried that too (should have mentioned that in my question, and I will now), and NuGet Package Explorer keeps changing it back to 1.0.0.  I'll make the change manually and see if that works

Comment: It seems you are not the only one experiencing the ["missing digit"](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3050) problem and having to do it manually. Holy cow!

Comment: That is quite a bummer.  Also, I'm not sure what all needs to happen manually.  I changed the file to a zip folder, extracted it, changed the version number in the .nuspec file, changed the version number in the folder name, rezipped the folder, changed the extension back to nupkg, and now when I open the "Manage Packages for Solution" in Visual Studio, it just says, Error occurred.

Comment: Well, changing the version number to 1.0.0.1 definitely persisted while using the NuGet Package Explorer, and when I restarted Visual Studio and removed the other NuGet package from the same local repo, it showed up in the Manage Packages for Solution GUI, but when I click install, I still get the same error (can't find in the following primary sources(s)) :(